# Chrome extension delay condition

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension which does something after its button is clicked.
However I dont want it be abused so I need the its code to be executed after some time.

How can I surround this code with a timeout in order to achieve this?

Thank you for reading me!

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
var Mp=tab.url.substring(0,23);
if(Mp=='https://www.example.com')
{
onWindowLoad();

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    if (request.action == "getSource")
    {
    ...Working here
    }
});
}
else
{
message.innerHTML='<span style="color: #f00">This is not a valid page</span>';
}
});

function onWindowLoad()
{
var message = document.querySelector('#message');
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "getPagesSource.js"});
}
```

Comment: Which button? The browser action button at the upperright corner?

Comment: Yes, that one right of the address bar.

Comment: Can you show your current code (please omit non-relevant details)?

Comment: What about the `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` event listener? That's also relevant. If you want to rate-limit the number of actions, just save a `Date.now()` reference. If you want to delay the action, use `clearTimeout` and `setTimeout`.

Comment: chrome.browserAction.onClicked=Should I add this somewhere?

How to save the date and how/where to use the setTimeout?

Comment: No, that's not the correct signature. You said that you're referring to the button in the upper-right corner, so I assumed that you meant a browserAction button with a [`chrome.browserAction.onClicked`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked) handler.

Comment: Im lost :)
This code is already working with a button up there.
I just want to be a time gap between 2 clicks (regarding that button), because Im sending an ajax request on each.

Comment: Are you using a [browser action popup](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#popups) instead of just the button? This does not matter, the logic for either case is the same. Have you already tried to implement one of the two methods I suggested in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023983/chrome-extension-delay-condition#comment19369003_14023983)?

Comment: Yes this code is in the popup.js.

As far for the two methods, I cant understand where and how I should try them. Im not even a begginer with extensions.

Comment: Someone can help me with this? I need a couple of lines to be added in my existing code.
Please dont give me suggestions. They dont help me, I dont have time to learn coding the extensions. I need a ready solution with that.

Comment: Ill pay someone to make this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make a compromise so just after the getSelected I added the following line:

```
chrome.browserAction.disable(tab.Id);
```

It disables the action button thus it cant be clicked while the script sends the data to the server, as with this extension I grab the tab url in order to store it in my database.
After the ajax response and adding the following

```
if(xhr.readyState==4)
{
message.innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
chrome.browserAction.enable(tab.Id); /////<---THAT LINE
}
```

the button gets ready again to be clicked.

I couldnt find the way to add a specific delay in seconds, this way seems stupid but its working, as the response's delay from my server is enough for switching the 2 states of the action button.

With this, however another problem came up, which Ill write in different question.