# Timer for chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chrome extension delay condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023983/chrome-extension-delay-condition)

Im very beginner at extensions and by collecting codes from here and there I created a simple one which collects the tab's url (works for specific website) and using ajax Im sending it to my server in order to store it in my database.
What Im trying to do is to add a timer so the browser button will be disabled (or do nothing) if the previous click occured in less than 5 seconds.

Below is the structure of the extension:

**Manifest:**

```
{
"name": "The name",
"icons": { "16": "Big.png",
       "48": "Big.png",
       "128": "Big.png" },
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "and the description",
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

**popup.js:**

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
var Mp=tab.url
if(Mp=='http://www.examplesite.com')
{
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
var Params;
xhr.open("POST", "http://myserver.com/post_from_extension.asp", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
Params='Url=' + tab.url;
xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xhr.readyState==4)
        {
        message.innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
xhr.send(Params);
}
else
{
message.innerHTML='<span style="font-family: Segoe UI, Tahoma;color: #f00">This is not a valid url</span>';
}
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style=''>
<head>
<script src='popup.js'></script>
</head>
<body style="width:400px;">
<div id='message'><span style="font-family: Segoe UI, Tahoma;color: #00f">Sending request</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As a side question, is there any other method to post the url in my database, if not with Ajax?

Thank you for reading me.

Comment: Please do not respost the same question (even if it's worded slightly differently), just edit your [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023983/chrome-extension-delay-condition) to add useful details.

Comment: Omg, could somebody really help me add a couple of code lines and have it ready? I will pay!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add a background page (script) to your extension - this is a kind of application state. Add this in the manifest:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
```

Then in the page you can define an array storing last times when browser action was performed for each tab.

```
var timers = [];
```

You can update this array's elements from your `popup.js`, something like that (in `getSelected` callback):

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().timers[tabId] = new Date();
chrome.browserAction.disable(tabId);
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "icon-disabled.png", tabId: tabId});
```

Note how you can disable browser action and change its appearence to a disable/grayed one.

When a period passed since the registered time exceeds 5 seconds you should re-enable the button from the background page.

```
var currentTime = new Date();
if(currentTime - chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().timers[tabId] > 5000)
{
  chrome.browserAction.enable(tabId);
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "icon-enabled.png", tabId: tabId});
}
```

You can execute this code from `setInterval` callback and within a cycle through all elements in the `timers` array.

Comment: I only managed to make chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "icon-disabled.png"}); to work, but everything else isnt working :(